# does maven shade plugin transformers accepts wildcards

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

Recently I found a solution to a problem with an application I'm working on.

Briefly: I was building my application with [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) and I was having a problem because JasperReport was giving me a `JRRuntimeException`. I solved it by adding a configuration to the shade plugin with [transformers](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html).

Now I was wondering if the transformers accept wildcards so you don't need to include every file as a resource. For instance, I would want something like

```
<transformers>
    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer">
        <!-- every .properties file will be merged (if name repeated elsewhere) -->
        <resource>*.*</resource>
    </transformer>
</transformers>
```

I found something in the examples about [`ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer) where `<basename>` is used but I don't quite understand how it works.

I anyone knows how the `ResourceTransformer` works and how to configure it to accomplish what I need, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify a wildcard with `ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer`. It uses a pattern to find `.properties` files for locales.
For example, if your resource bundles are under `src/main/resources/i18n/messages`, just configure your transformer this way:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceBundleAppendingTransformer">
    <basename>i18n/messages</basename>
</transformer>
```